# Western Digital MyCloud EX2 can't see USB drives

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas

I have a new WD EX2 with 8TB of storage. The device and storage are working fine. I'm using the device's built in management site under `http://wdmycloudex2.local/` and I should be able to plug in a USB external drive to be part of the NAS setup however none of the drives are ever recognized. The drives work fine if plugged into a PC/Mac and I've tried various file systems as well.